# Rails - How to calculate daily, weekly, mothly total price on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

[image]I have Ticket sold model with params `:quantity, :price`

```
in my application.record.rb
def total_price
 Ticket.sum(:price)
end

in my ticket index
<% @tickets.each do |t| %>
  t.total_price
<% end %>
```

It Worked but it calculated all of ticket total price.

What i want is i can separating between daily total price, weekly total price and monthly total price.

How to do that? 
Please help and thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For daily total price

```
def daily_total_price
 Ticket.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day).sum(:subtotal)
end
```

For weekly total price

```
def weekly_total_price
 Ticket.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).sum(:subtotal)
end
```

For monthly total price

```
def monthly_total_price
 Ticket.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month).sum(:subtotal)
end
```

Last 7 days total

```
def last_7_day_total_price
  Ticket.where("created_at >= ? ", (Date.today - 7.days).beginning_of_day).sum(:subtotal)
end
```

Last 30 days total

```
def last_30_day_total_price
  Ticket.where("created_at >= ? ", (Date.today - 30.days).beginning_of_day).sum(:subtotal)
end
```

In view

```
<% @tickets.each do |t| %>
  Daily total price: - <%=t.daily_total_price%>
  Weekly total price: - <%=t.weekly_total_price%>
  #.....so on..
<% end %>
```

Comment: sir i put a picture inside what exactly i want. please take a look thank you

Comment: @Garbela Is subtotal a fiedl?

Comment: subtotal:float sir

Comment: @Garbela So are you saving subtotal value while creating each record for sold ticket?

Comment: Yes sir, def subtotal quantity * price end

Comment: @Garbela Check the update answer , it will work for you. also let me know for further guidance, incase you are already saving subtotal then you should use `sum(:subtotal)`

Comment: @Garbela Do you have `subtoatl` column in ticekt model? and are you saving it's column value.

Comment: @Garbela Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you!

Comment: i got problem on daily_total_price. daily_total_price follows daily_total_price of the last day. eg on september29 daily_total_price is 100$, on september30 is 150$. when i use Ticket.daily_total_price, daily_total_price of september29 changed to 150$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following model scopes -

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord

  scope :daily_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.beginning_of_day, date_time.end_of_day).sum(:subtotal) }
  scope :weekly_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.beginning_of_week, date_time.end_of_week).sum(:subtotal) }
  scope :monthly_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.at_beginning_of_month, date_time.end_of_month).sum(:subtotal) }

  scope :last_7d_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at >= ?', (date_time - 7.days).beginning_of_day).sum(:subtotal) }
  scope :last_30d_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at >= ?', (date_time - 30.days).beginning_of_day).sum(:subtotal) }

end
```

Usage of Scopes

```
Ticket.daily_total_price # For daily scope 
Ticket.weekly_total_price # For Weekly scope 
Ticket.monthly_total_price # For monthly scope 
Ticket.last_7d_total_price # For last 7 days scope 
Ticket.last_30d_total_price # For 30 days scope
```

Also you can pass a specific date as argument

```
# With time zone
date_time_with_zone = Time.zone.parse("2018-09-30")
Ticket.daily_total_price(date_time_with_zone)

# Without time zone
date_time = Time.parse("2018-09-30")
Ticket.daily_total_price(date_time)
```

I hope it should work for your requirement.

Comment: i got problem on daily_total_price. daily_total_price follows daily_total_price of the last day. eg on september29 daily_total_price is 100$, on september30 is 150$. when i use Ticket.daily_total_price, daily_total_price of september29 changed to 150$

Comment: Ticket.daily_total_price scope return the todays total price. Also you can supply the specific date. Ex - Ticket.daily_total_price(Time.zone.parse("2018-09-30"))