# Rails: How to sum total price per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to calculate total price of ticket sales on the day it sold.

But it shows total price of the last day (Today's total price).

**What i got now :**

```
October 20

Ticket 1    USD 1.11
Ticket 2    USD 2.22
Ticket 3    USD 3.33

Total For Today
USD 7.77 (HERE'S THE PROBLEM)

-------------------------------
October 21

Ticket 1    USD 1.11
Ticket 2    USD 2.22
Ticket 3    USD 4.44

Today's total
USD 7.77
```

**What i exactly want is :**

```
October 20

Ticket 1    USD 1.11
Ticket 2    USD 2.22
Ticket 3    USD 3.33

Today's total
USD 6.66

-------------------------------
October 21

Ticket 1    USD 1.11
Ticket 2    USD 2.22
Ticket 3    USD 4.44

Total For Today    USD 7.77
```

What i want is how to calculate total price of each day (total price on the day those tickets has been sold)?

In ticket model

```
scope :daily_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.beginning_of_day, date_time.end_of_day).sum(:price) }
```

In Ticket controller

```
def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @users = User.all
end
```

In Ticket index

```
<% tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <%= ticket.created_at.strftime("%d %B") %>
  <%= ticket.user.username %>
  <%= ticket.price %>
<% end %>

<%= Ticket.daily_total_price) %>
```

Thank for helping :)

Comment: probably the dates are overlapping and is computing the 1.11 from the next day?

Comment: @Garbela in your tickets/index.html.erb you are passing in `Time.zone.parse("2018-10-23")` directly to your `Ticket.daily_total_price()`. You need to pass in a date-time that corresponds to the date of the tickets above it. In other words, (assuming you have another outer loop that you didn't show in your index.html.erb to loop through each day, then something like `<%= Ticket.daily_total_price(tickets.first.created_at) %>` would work

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Yes,its worked.. Thank you so much sir :)

Comment: @Garbela no problem! :)) Good luck further!

Comment: You might get wrong grouping by date for your local time. You can do `scope :daily_total_price, ->(date_time = Time.current)` instead and than compare displayed dates and times if than right for your clock.

Comment: Briefly described the solution related to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52584685/8439462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do what you want, I'd imagine the following code...

```
<% date_for_group = nil %>

<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>

  <% if ticket.created_at.to_date != date_for_group %>
    <%# show total of previous group %>
    <% if date_for_group %>
      <br/>
      Total for <%=date_for_group.strftime("%d %B") %></br>
      <%= Ticket.daily_total_price(date_for_group) %>
      <br/>
    <% end %>

    <%= ticket.created_at.strftime("%d %B") %>
    <br/>
    <% date_for_group = ticket.created_at.to_date %>
  <% end %>

  <%= ticket.user.username %>
  <%= ticket.price %>
<% end %>

<% if date_for_group %>
  <br/>
  Total for <%=date_for_group.strftime("%d %B") %></br>
  <%= Ticket.daily_total_price(date_for_group) %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Another question, how can i group total price for a month? ex: october's total, november's total etc..? thanks

Comment: Sounds like a new question!  Why don't you post the question and show what you've tried?  The solution should be similar to the above, but you'll need a `Ticket.montly_total_price(date)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
<%= Ticket.daily_total_price %>
```

But that always defaults the first argument to today's date (you wrote `->(date_time = Time.now)` What you want to do is to pass the appropriate date in...  put the date into a '@date' instance variable in your controller and then do...

```
<%= Ticket.daily_total_price(@date) %>
```

Comment: How to put the date into a '@date' instance variable in controller?

Comment: Show us the code where you're bulding the `tickets` variable.  That's where you want to assign the date to a vartiable as well...

Comment: sorry i dont understand.

Comment: What should i write on my controller?

Comment: In tickets/index.rb you're doing `<% tickets.each do |ticket| %>` so you've defined `tickets` somewhere, right?  In your `TicketsController` ?  Can you please show that code?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look sir. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've posted another answer that shows how you can generate totals when the created_at is a new day.