# Rails Calculate Total Sales

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm finding the sum of total value of sales(orders). Basically, adding together the price of each product sold.

code below is close to the solution but I don’t have a price (:price) column in my Order table as I’m picking the price from Product table =>  order.product.price

How can I add the product :price in the syntax showing below in the Order.rb?

order.rb  Ref: [Rails: How to sum total price per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946245/rails-how-to-sum-total-price-per-day)

```
scope :total_sales, ->(date_time = Time.now) { where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.beginning_of_day, date_time.end_of_day).sum(:price) }
```

OrdersController.rb

```
def sales
   @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
 end
```

sales.html.erb

```
Order.total_sales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An order only has one product? If so something like:

```
joins(:product).where('orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', date_time.beginning_of_day, date_time.end_of_day).sum('products.price')
```

Comment: I tried it, getting error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column orders.price does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(orders.price) FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "products" ON "...    scope :total_sales, ->(date_time = Time.now) { joins(:product).where('orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',date_time.beginning_of_day, date_time.end_of_day).sum('orders.price') }

Comment: Check @Jon's answer. It's `sum('products.price')` not `orders.price`

Comment: Perfect! my bad, sum('products.price') works. Many thanks guys